# spawn function in erlang using function in another module

Tags: erlang

I have been learning erlang for the past week and am going through Joe Armstrong's Pragmatic erlang book . I was writing some code to spawn processes and have come across a situation
I have a function in module myatom.erl which looks like this

```
 start(anatom,Fun) ->
       case whereis(anatom) of
               undefined -> 
                       Pid = spawn(Fun),
                       try register(anatom,Pid) of
                               true -> true
                      catch
                       error:Reason ->
                              Reason
                      end;
              Other -> {error,already_defined}
      end.
```

There is a function in another module named tloop.erl

```
loop() ->
   receive 
        { From , No } -> From ! { self(), No*4};
        Other -> void
   end.
```

if I am to use start() to spawn loop in the erlang shell , how can I do it ?
I get the following error when I do

```
anatom:start(atomname,tloop:loop).
```

Thanks in advance !

```
anatom:start(myatom,fun tloop:loop). 
* 2: syntax error before: ')
```

Answer (score 2):

You must write the following

```
anatom:start(myatom, fun tloop:loop/0).
```

You have to specify the arity (number of arguments) of the function, as in erlang functions with the same name but different arity are not considered to be the same function.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
However that doesnt work out too , I believe the real reason is when we call the function with a new atom say newatom , erlang cannot match any pattern in start's body with (newatom , fun). It expects all calls to match (myatom, fun). So I replaced myatom in the body with AnAtom and it works

Comment: Sure, function parameters must match :)